# how to use web and server tracking for GA4 using GTM

Tags: google-tag-manager, server-side, event-tracking, google-analytics-4

I'm using GTM to install the two tags of GA4 (Web and server), the problem is how to eliminate the duplicated events coming from the two sources (Web and server), I used an Event_id as an event parameter but I still see the duplicate event in GA4 with the same event id !!

Comment: Afaik GA4 does not have a mechanism to automatically deduplicate events based on a unique event_id (opposed to the Facebook Conversion API, which does).
At this point, I would recommend sending GA4 events only through the Serverside GTM. Also, the clientside events are less relevant for GA4 as it does not depend on a 3rd-party cookie (again, as opposed to the Facebook Pixel).

Comment: Thanks. Your answear help me a lot